# What does, "gis "f38498f8-1663-4f2d-b17c-e50aefa2c1c9 @!0,0;BDH" is ready" means? Ever since I upgraded to 20.04, I am seeing this message

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lts, window-manager

Whenever I boot 20.04, I see this window for like a few seconds. I wonder what it is? It disappears after some time. Sometimes [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y4ft.jpg) closes itself last longer than expected; up to like 30 seconds. Trying to close that window is pointless because it won't.
[image: Annyoing pointless window]

This is a pop-up message I see in the notification area.

[image: A pop-up message in the notification area.]

If someone knows what it is, I all ears. If this is a bug, I am only experiencing then do let me know. It's really annoying to bear this and not to do anything about it. So, I asked.

*Any forms of tips/info/corrections are highly appreciated.*

```
blkid
/dev/sda3: UUID="1a37750c-ce10-4266-b275-5eb4d7169b09" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="90ff6cd0-a29f-e34c-a6c0-f83deb6bd898"
/dev/sda1: UUID="A5A0-71F7" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="728daa10-9d47-4a5a-a2ac-3848e31277b0"
/dev/sda2: UUID="959ae50f-748b-4a2c-ab74-7a3ff34c232b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="acacd87b-6422-4541-8b0c-753fd208556e"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="bpool" UUID="8068478147717291498" UUID_SUB="1412347502323350688" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="043f5dd1-4ccf-7c4b-be8a-8c41dda3340e"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="rpool" UUID="14553914639675756316" UUID_SUB="3606586328494988203" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="bac1f4df-8ce1-6f45-9429-6d83e5c7227c"
```

Comment: Is it the same code every time it pops up?  Maybe check `blkid` on your system and see if that is a matching UUID for a drive.  `gjs` is a GNOME Javascript binding.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on it, so we might all be in this together trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Terrance my blkid looks like this: https://pastebin.com/5rQsfwx5 I wonder, how to match UUID.